# Constraints for labels with unspecified number of lines in tableview cell

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, constraints

I tried to add constraints to three labels but I don't want to specify heights of them. Name (Pharmacy), address and number should have one or more lines. Now I added constraints to name, address and numer just like in the attachments but they don't work. 
What's wrong with them? 
Thank you for your response.
Greetings Alex
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: have you tried my solution ? your issue resolved ?

Answer (score 1):

Better solution is to use `UIStackView` instead of manual Constraints.. `StackViews` will make your life easy
For this Scenario you will have 1 `vertical Stack` within which you will have `3 horizontal Stack` ... Set `Stack` fill mode Proportional ...